# Unitary group of a von Neumann algebra: is it a retract of $U(H)$?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M\subset B(H)$ be a properly infinite von Neumann algebra (the case I care about is $M=$ hyperfinite $\mathrm{III}_1$).

Consider the unitary groups $U(M)$ and $U(H)$ in their strong operator topologies.

Does the inclusion map $U(M)\hookrightarrow U(H)$ admit a continuous retraction $U(H)\rightarrow U(M)$?
Does it admit a retraction which is furthermore equivariant for the left actions of $U(M)$?

Comment: Since unitaries generates the  whole  algebras is it reasonable to ask the similar  question for  existence of retraction for $M\to B(H)$? Can one imagine a possible relation betwen these two questions?

Comment: I mean that: assume that  we  have  such a retraction then we  extend it  to a retraction $B(H)\to M$  since every element has  a standard expression in terms of unitaries. So  what would be happen? Are there relation between these two questions?

Comment: A possible relation between your  question and  existence of linear retraction $B(H)\to M$?

Comment: I doubt that a retraction $B(H) \to M$ would help. Indeed, if $M$ is finite dimensional, then there does exists a linear retraction $B(H) \to M$, but there typically does not exist a retraction $U(H) \to U(M)$.

Comment: this situation remind me some papers of F.Ghahrqmany about extension of cerain maps between spheres of Banach space to linear maps between Banach space. I vaguely remember th e details. I read them about 10 or 15 years ago